# Using react this.state in other components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, mern

I have state which which contains thumbnail of my video files, i have watch button which on click navigate you to new page (component) each particular thumbnail has a name and file info, i map through the thumbnail state, how do pass the file info to the component you are navigated as your click the watch button

```js
  {this.state.Poster.map(poster =>
              <Col md="3 " className="" >
                <Card className="card-user card-transparent">
                  <CardImg top src=     {`/files/${poster.filename}`}>
                </CardImg>
                    <CardText className="py-3 px-3">
                      <div className="card-description">
                      <h5 className="display-5 text-Movie-white text-center" >
                      {poster.metadata.name}
                      </h5>
                      <p className="text-center">{poster.metadata.Description}
                      </p>
                      </div>
                 </CardText>
                <CardFooter>
                      <div className="button-container  py-3"><a href="movie/">
             <Button className="btn-fill btn-movie " color="primary" >
                          Watch
             </Button></a>
                      </div>
                    </CardFooter>
                  </Card>
                </Col>
            )}
```

Comment: how do you navigate from the first component to the second? With `react-router`, it's as simple as passing a plain javascript object as the second parameter.

Comment: Yes with react router dom

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the `history` object's `push` method, like so:

```
goTo: (route, state) => {
 this.props.history.push(route, state);
}

...
// in your .map callback
<SomeComponentOrDom onClick={() => this.goTo('/SomewhereElse', { id: poster.id })}>
  Something
</SomeComponentOrDom>

...
// in SomewhereElse
constructor(props) {
  this.state = {
    posterId: props.history.location.state.id
  }
}
```

Of course, you should make your code more defensive and check for `null` in different places.

Here you can find [the doc for history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history).